# setting up a form in php/mysqli

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I'm working on this quiz. Something has gone wrong with my form though. The page displays a random question but instead of showing 4 different answer options, it repeats one option 4 times. How do should I go about fixing this?

```
    <?php
    //retrieve question list:
    $get_questions = $con->prepare("SELECT question_ID, question FROM questions");
    $get_questions->execute();
    $get_questions->bind_result($question_ID, $question);

    $questions = array();

    while ($get_questions->fetch()) {

    $questions[$question_ID] = array($question_ID, $question, array());
    }

    // retrieve answer list:
    $get_answers = $con->prepare("SELECT id, question_ID, answers, correct FROM answers");
    $get_answers->execute();
    $get_answers->bind_result($id, $question_ID, $answers, $correct);

    while ($get_answers->fetch()) {
        $questions[$question_ID][2][$id] = array($id, $answers, $correct);
    }

    // Scramble the array and print:
    shuffle($questions);
    ?>
    <form method="get" action="result.php">
<div class="question">
                <label><h2><?php echo $question ?></h2></label>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="question<?php echo $question_ID ?>_id" value="<?php echo $question_ID; ?>" id="question<?php echo $question_ID; ?>_id"/>
                <input name="answer<?php echo $id ?>" id="q<?php echo $id ?>_a1" value="1" type="radio"/>
                <label for="q<?php echo $id ?>_a1"> <?php echo $answers ?></label><br>
                <input name="answer<?php echo $id?>" id="q<?php echo $id ?>_a2" value="2" type="radio"/>
                <label for="q<?php echo $id ?>_a2"> <?php echo $answers ?></label><br>
                <input name="answer<?php echo $answers ?>" id="q<?php echo $id ?>_a3" value="3" type="radio"/>
                <label for="q<?php echo $id ?>_a3"> <?php echo $answers ?></label><br>
                <input name="answer<?php echo $id ?>" id="q<?php echo $id ?>_a4" value="4" type="radio"/>
                <label for="q<?php echo $id ?>_a4"> <?php echo $answers ?></label><br>
            </div>




<?php
echo "<br><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
echo "</form></body></html>";
?>


</form>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: You echo `$answers` each time, but `$answers` is not defined anywhere. Is your form display in a loop? Do you have variables defined somewhere else in your script? If so, we'll need those, too.

Comment: I believe you need to learn how PHP variables work. You are echoing the same variable repeatedly! Why aren't you fetching them from the `$questions` array?

Comment: i've only just started working with phpmyadmin. no my form is not currently in a loop. i don't have variable defined anywhere else. i was attempting to call the choices from my answers table in the database but it occurs me to the table and the column i'm trying to call have the same name >.<

Comment: So, we're basically helping you get an A on your quiz, right? Sounds like academic dishonesty to me!

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob i was simply hoping to correct the code i already have written, i'm not asking anyone to rewrite it for me.